# Expectation of a Hebbian term

Tags: expected-value

In a paper by [Akrout et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05391.pdf), it is mentioned that

> [Given $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ is an
> input vector, $\mathbf{W}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix, and $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the output
> vector] we observe that
> $$E\left[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{T}\right]=E\left[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{W}^{T}\right]=E\left[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{T}\right] \mathbf{W}^{T}$$
> In the simplest case, if the elements of $\mathbf{x}$
> are independent and zero-mean with equal variance, $σ^2$, it follows
> that $$E[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{y}^T] = σ^2\mathbf{W}^T. $$

I'm trying to show this numerically. I sample $N=50$, $m-$dimensional vectors $\mathbf{x}$, sampled a random weight matrix $\mathbf{W}$, and computed the resulting $\mathbf{y}$. Then, I measured the angle between the term $\mathbf{x} \mathbf{y}^T$ and $\mathbf{W}^T$ and was expecting to get a value close to zero. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np


def normalize_vec(vector):
    """
        normalize input vector.
    """
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)


def measure_angle(v1, v2):
    """
        Compute angle between two vectors.
    """
    n1 = normalize_vec(v1.squeeze())
    n2 = normalize_vec(v2.squeeze())

    return np.nan_to_num((np.arccos(np.einsum('i, i -> ', n1, n2)) * 180 / np.pi))

# -- initialize
m = 784
n = 170
n_sample = 50
W = np.random.rand(m, n) - 0.5
x = np.random.rand(n_sample, m) - 0.5 

# -- compute y
y = np.matmul(x, W)

# -- compute xy^T
xy = np.matmul(x.T, y)

# -- measure angle
print(measure_angle(W.ravel(), xy.ravel()))
```

which returns the a value of ~75 degrees. Also, measuring the difference

```
# -- measure norm
print(np.linalg.norm(np.std(x)**2*W - xy))
```

returns 1783.196.

1. I was expecting that $\mathbf{x} \mathbf{y}^T$ and $σ^2\mathbf{W}^T$ have the same direction and size. Why this is not the case?
2. Otherwise, how should I verify the equality mentioned in the paper?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  As for your question: could you explain what you mean by the "size" and "direction" of a *matrix*?  And by the "equality in the paper" would you mean $E[XX^\prime]=\sigma^2\mathbb{I}_m$? If so, that's an immediate consequence of the assumptions about $X.$ It basically restates those assumptions in matrix form.

Comment: @whuber 1) I transform each matrix into a vector, then measure the angle between them. If the matrices are equal, I expect this angle to be small. 2) If 2 matrices are equal, I expect that if I subtract one from the other, and then take the norm of the resulting matrix, the value be close to zero. 3) By equality in the paper I mean $E[xy^T]=\sigma^2W^T$. If my assumptions are correct, why the numerical test does not corroborate that? Is there a mistake in my numerical test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is about the equality $E_{p(\mathbf x)}\left[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{W}^{T}\right]=E_{p(\mathbf x)}\left[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{T}\right] \mathbf{W}^{T}$ which is a special case of $E_{p(\mathbf x)}\left[\mathbf{A}(\mathbf x) \mathbf{B}\right]=E_{p(\mathbf x)}\left[\mathbf{A}(\mathbf x)\right] \mathbf{B}$.

> 2. Otherwise, how should I verify the equality mentioned in the paper?

This equality is a fundamental mathematical result and the paper you mention doesn't need to provide a proof because the statement is seen as common knowledge.

It follows directly from the [linearity of the expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184965/what-is-linearity-of-expectations) and the linearity of matrix multiplication. The matrix multiplication is a weighted sum (per entry) and as such a linear operator. The linearity of the expectation says that even if you don't have a discrete distribution $p(\mathbf x)$, where the expectation is just a weighted sum $E_{p(\mathbf x)} f(\mathbf x) = \sum_{\mathbf x} p(\mathbf x) f(\mathbf x)$, the expectation still behaves like a weighted sum in the following respect. You can generally change the order in which you apply weighted sums (and more generally linear operators like expectations), without changing the result.
In our case, you can first apply the multiplication with $\mathbf B$ and then the expectation or first apply the expectation and then the multiplication with $\mathbf B$, without changing the result.

If you want to proof the equality in detail, you could compare the  $i,j$-th entry of both sides of the equation, writing out what the matrix multiplication does to each entry. It'll be a weighted sum that can [switch places with the expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184965/what-is-linearity-of-expectations).

> 1. I was expecting that $\mathbf{x} \mathbf{y}^T$ and $σ^2\mathbf{W}^T$ have the same direction and size. Why this is not the case?

This sounds as if you try to show equality between $\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^T$ and $σ^2\mathbf{W}^T$. But the actual equality is between
$E_{p(\mathbf{x})}\left[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^T\right]$ and $σ^2\mathbf{W}^T$.
And I think this is what you meant to write.

You can approximate the expectation as an average over sample points $\frac1N\sum_{\mathbf{x}\sim p(\mathbf{x})}\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^T$ and then see whether this average is close to
$σ^2\mathbf{W}^T$.

In fact with

```
xy = np.matmul(x.T, y)
```

you compute a sum over the sample dimension. The only issue is that you forgot to divide by `n_sample`:

```
xy = np.matmul(x.T, y)/n_sample
```

This change doesn't affect the angle but drastically decreases the
distance norm. Note that an angle between two vectorized matrices may not be a well-motivated measure, but it should still return zero if the matrices are exactly equal to each other. Since random vectors in high-dimensional spaces are usually close to orthogonal, 75 degrees is not a bad sign.

In high-dimensional spaces, it's also normal that you need more than `n_sample = 50` sample points for a good approximation of the expectation. For `n_sample = 1000` I get about `42.` degrees and a distance of about `8.` while `n_sample = 100000` gives about `5.` degrees and a distance of about `0.8`. The values go (on average) closer to zero the more sample points you use.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would verify that $E(xy^T) = \sigma^2 W^T$ using R.  I don't think the angle method works because you are creating a large vector out of the matrix and getting the angle between the vectors.  I have not proven that is possible given all the assumptions, so I will stick to showing that $E(xy^T) - \sigma^2 W^T = 0$

```
set.seed(1985)

n <- 784
m <- 170
nsamples <- 2000
W <- matrix(runif(m*n, -0.5, 0.5), nrow = n, ncol = m)

res <- numeric(nsamples)
for (i in 1:nsamples)
{
  x <- matrix(rnorm(m), ncol = 1)
  y <- W %*% x
  res[i] <- mean(x %*% t(y) - 1 * t(W))
}

mean(res)

W <- matrix(runif(m*n, -0.5, 0.5), nrow = n, ncol = m)

res <- numeric(nsamples)
for (i in 1:nsamples)
{
  x <- matrix(rnorm(m, 0, 2), ncol = 1)
  y <- W %*% x
  res[i] <- mean(x %*% t(y) - 4 * t(W))
}

mean(res)
```

Both means are very close to zero.